# Rails routing with subdirectories

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have "standart" mvc... In layout i'm rendering partial from `art_lookups`
it look's so:

```
= form_tag :controller => 'art_lookups', :action => 'search' do
  = text_field_tag :search, params[:search], :pattern=>".{4,24}", :class => "search-input", :placeholder => "Введите код детали"
  = submit_tag "Поиск", :name => nil, :class => "search-submit"
```

and layout part:

```
= render :partial => 'art_lookups/search'
```

All is ok.

But now i'm creating admin part... And i have controller and view in subdirectory `admin`, and if i try to go to some view in admin, i get error like

```
No route matches {:controller=>"admin/art_lookups", :action=>"search"}
```

How to solve it?

Also part of route:

```
namespace :admin do
    resources :orders
  end
```

If i comment all in partial, all is ok...
Also when i write in admin/orders/index

```
= link_to "Редактирование", edit_admin_orders(o)
```

i get routing error to...

Comment: change `resources :orders` to `resources :art_lookups` will work?

Comment: @KienThanh will not work, becouse art_lookups doesn't belong to admin part

Comment: maybe add something like this under your admin controller route: `get 'admin/art_lookups' => :search`

Comment: @stsd this will not help, till i haven't this partial in admin directory

Answer (score 1):

Change `edit_admin_orders(o)` to `edit_admin_order_path(o)`, it will not get routing error.

**Updated:** Add route for search action

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :orders do
    collection do
      get 'search'
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: @PavelBY okay, i posted answer for solve it. Make sure you have a `search` action in your controller.

Comment: @PavelBY, if the Kien's answer solved your problem consider accepting it as the correct answer

Comment: I didn't have any search in admin controller! that is the question! no view, no controller with search in admin!  all is out of admin